# Rotating an armature bone moves other parts and breaks the character's mesh

Tags: mesh, armature

I have a very simple armature and a mesh attached to it.
When I rotate a bone, it tears and deforms the mesh.

[image]

**Here is a video of the problem:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fp4eVufmFULBkA9F6RfzgGbg0VQDxrpT/view?usp=sharing

**And here is the .blender file if you need it:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zzM10MO_6ShL7DPa4okvsudUKcKqvQTU/view?usp=sharing

Did I do something wrong with the armature? If so, how can I fix it so it moves the way it should and doesn't tear or deform the mesh.

*The mesh created by Bunny on Sketchfab:*
*"Cats - Rigged and Posed" (https://skfb.ly/6SUQF) by Bunny is licensed under Creative Commons Attribution (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/).*

Comment: You have to properly paint the weights.

Comment: Ohh I see, thanks for the quick reply!